# Get error at uploading Excel file in java

Tags: java, windows, spring

Hi I make one function in netbeans for upload file using spring but it not working, I send my controller code below please correct code

```
    org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.j                                                                                        ava:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.j                                                                                        ava:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineVal                                                                                        ve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.jav                                                                                        a:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProcessor.process(AjpProcessor.java:200)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(                                                                                        AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoin                                                                                        t.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.                                                                                        java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor                                                                                        .java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
    java.lang.RuntimeException: D:/101-200 (2003).xls (No such file or directory)
    at Controller.AdminExelSheetController.read(AdminExelSheetController.jav                                                                                        a:323)
    at Controller.AdminExelSheetController.onSubmit(AdminExelSheetController                                                                                        .java:93)
    at Controller.AdminExelSheetController.onSubmit(AdminExelSheetController                                                                                        .java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleFormController.processFormS                                                                                        ubmission(SimpleFormController.java:272)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractFormController.handleRequ                                                                                        estInternal(AbstractFormController.java:268)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(                                                                                        AbstractController.java:153)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.ha                                                                                        ndle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:48)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(Dispatch                                                                                        erServlet.java:923)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(Dispatche                                                                                        rServlet.java:852)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(Frame                                                                                        workServlet.java:882)
     at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServ
```

At the above code I import file using FileInputStream but this code is not working . I don't upload file , i get error msg  .In this project I am using spring framework and hibernate
at above code tell me where is the problem

My Controller code is below

```
public static Vector read(File fileName) {
    Vector rowStore = new Vector();
    try {
        FileInputStream inputFile = null;
        try {
            inputFile = new FileInputStream("D:/" + fileName);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e.getMessage());
        }
        POIFSFileSystem systemFile = new POIFSFileSystem(inputFile);
        HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(systemFile);
        HSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
        Iterator rows = sheet.rowIterator();
        if (!"".equals(rows.toString())) {
            while (rows.hasNext()) {
                HSSFRow row = (HSSFRow) rows.next();
                Iterator cells = row.cellIterator();
                Vector cellStore = new Vector();
                while (cells.hasNext()) {
                    HSSFCell cell = (HSSFCell) cells.next();
                    cellStore.addElement(cell);
                }
                rowStore.addElement(cellStore);
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return rowStore;
}
```

Comment: Please reduce your code to a minimal, properly formatted example that reproduces your issue. Add the stacktrace/compiler errors that you get.

Comment: I reduce my code. please check above read method . using this read method i want upload file but it's not working something wrong. give me proper solution

Comment: `properly formatted`, `add the stacktrace/compiler errors that you get`. Define `not working`/`something wrong`

Comment: I don't get any error but my upload file function not working. my file not uploaded

Comment: can you give me code for upload file in database

Comment: I get this type error for file upload funcation

Comment: hi I add compiler error above please check it

Comment: `D:/101-200 (2003).xls (No such file or directory)` is probably one of your problems. Please still leave the code. A proper analysis is only possible if we see both.

Comment: @Himanshu Deriya: you deleted to much - there is noting left then the exception, that is not very usefull.

Comment: @ Ralph: what can i do for this function . i want start this function

Comment: @reto sir , what can i do for this code ,you want see my code ya anything

Comment: can any one give me proper solution

Answer (score 0):

In the tags you say you are on a windows OS, then your error is in the Path definition. In windows the Path is declared by "\" and not by "/".

In java the \ symbol is the escape symbol, so you have to escape to use it (sry for the many "escape" :D): the code would look like this:

```
inputFile = new FileInputStream("D:\\" + fileName);
```